# How to read an excel file in go?

Tags: excel, go

I'm new on the go lang.I want to read an excel file for procees it later, but I don't know how to read the file in go? Anyone can show me an example ?

Comment: i created this before, might help...
http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2014/07/golang-working-with-microsoft-excel.html

Answer (score 17):

I haven't tried it but there's an [xlsx package](http://github.com/tealeg/xlsx).

Install it with

```
go get -v github.com/tealeg/xlsx
```

Read the [documentation](http://godoc.org/github.com/tealeg/xlsx) and come back here with some code you've tried if you get stuck.

Comment: I've used this library for input and output of (moderately) simple files, and it worked well.

Comment: Thank you for adding a bit of real world experience, Felix!

Comment: Any suggestion package for xls not xlsx?

Comment: There is a better package call excelize.  Package can be found here https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize.git

Answer (score 2):

The [`go-ole` package](https://github.com/mattn/go-ole/) looks like a way to go if you want to drive an Excel process via COM to read your file.

Comment: tealeg/xlsx only support partial function and .xlsx only. So, this is better solution. But, you must use go on windows.